# Can Keras highlight loss that improves?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

From what I understand, Lasagna automatically highlights loss that improves. I think it would be very helpful if Keras can do the same, but I cannot seem to find a way to do that.

Comment: can i know why is this downvoted please?

Comment: It may be because your question was not of high quality (not even used a spell checker) but I don't know who did. Keras supports printing the loss during training and there are callbacks that send data to TensorBoard for example, what exactly do you want? Can you outline the behavior of Lasagna better or show examples like images/videos of this feature?

Comment: Note that val_loss is a measure suited for regression whereas accuracy is more suited for classification. I hope you meant regression problem here.

Comment: Are you able to solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I use Keras for performing non-linear regression. 
I use the `checkpointer` and the `fit` methods in the following way :

```
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath=weightsFile, verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
 predictivemodel.fit(X, y, nb_epoch=50, batch_size=100, show_accuracy=True,verbose=1, validation_split=0.2, callbacks=[EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=15, mode='min'),checkpointer])
```

I get a log file, and whenever `val_loss` improves, that part of the log file displays the following lines :

```
159900/159987 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.5797 - acc: 0.1123Epoch 00000: val_loss improved from inf to 0.46812, saving model to C:\Users\keras\experiment\dnnModels\weights\weights.hdf5
```

For the epoch, where the `val_loss` does not improve, I get following line in the log file :

```
159900/159987 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 0.3379 - acc: 0.1786Epoch 00007: val_loss did not improve
```